# PostgreSQL Custom Sequencing

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

Is there a built-in method in PostgreSQL or a custom method I can use to create a custom sequence column?

```
Example: AAA-2022-0001 
         AAA-2022-0002
         BAC-2022-0001
         ABC-2022-0001
         BAC-2022-0002
         AAA-2022-0003
```

Comment: i doubt it, why not create it in your code?

Comment: I was thinking of a less expensive way of implementing it.

Comment: your column doesn't seem to have an algorithmic way to produce it, so sql will not be possible. If you have an algorithm, you can implement it in any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequencing on PostgreSQL is performed by creating a Sequence. If when we use serial by creating a table then DB automatically created one sequence for this table. After then sets to `default value` of the `id` field this:
`nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)`. `nextval` is a PostgreSQL function that are increase sequence values and update. Because for sequencing we must create `sequence` using this table. But, we need a `primary key` in a custom format. And for this, we can create our own function that returns a formatted primary key value and we can set this function to `default value` of the `id` field. Please see to examples of our SQL queries:

```
-- creating our sequence 
CREATE SEQUENCE tbl_status_idx_seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    START 1
    CACHE 1
    NO CYCLE;


-- create function that will be returned unique id value in custom format 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_nextval()
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
declare 
    p_val int4; 
    v_ret text;
begin
    
    p_val = nextval('tbl_status_idx_seq'::regclass); 
    v_ret = 'AAA-' || extract(year from now())::text || '-' || lpad(p_val::text, 6, '0');
    
    return v_ret;  
  
end;
$function$;


-- creating our table for testing and use our function on the default value of id field. 
CREATE TABLE tbl_status (
    "id" text NOT NULL DEFAULT get_nextval(),
    "timestamp" timestamp NULL,
    state text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_status_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);



-- inserting sample data for testing and viewing our id value 
INSERT INTO tbl_status ("timestamp", "state") 
VALUES('2022-01-15 00:00:00.000', 'online');

INSERT INTO tbl_status ("timestamp", "state") 
VALUES('2022-02-03 00:00:00.000', 'deactivated');

INSERT INTO tbl_status ("timestamp", "state") 
VALUES('2022-03-20 00:00:00.000', 'disconnected');


-- and selecting table 
select * from tbl_status;


-- Result: 

id                      timestamp                       state
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 AAA-2022-000003         2022-01-15 00:00:00.000         online
 AAA-2022-000004         2022-02-03 00:00:00.000         deactivated
 AAA-2022-000005         2022-03-20 00:00:00.000         disconnected
```